# Data pointer is <QArrayData::shared_null+24> when accessing data of Qt3DRender::QBuffer

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I have such statements:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QAttribute *attribute = // ...

const float *posBufferPtr =
                reinterpret_cast<const float *>(attribute->buffer()->data().constData());
```

Generally, the pointer `posBufferPtr` is:

[image: Normal pointer value]

However, sometimes pointer value becomes strange:

[image: Strange pointer value]

I wonder what is the meaning of `<QArrayData::shared_null+24>`? I'm asking this, since when the pointer value is strange, my application gets messed up.

### UPDATE

I fixed the bug by making sure my buffer contains data:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer *mesh = // ...

Qt3DRender::QGeometry *meshGeometry = mesh->geometry();

for (Qt3DRender::QAttribute *attribute : meshGeometry->attributes()) {
    Qt3DRender::QBuffer *buf = attribute->buffer();
    if (buf) {
        // If buffer is empty, use data-generator to make data available
        if (buf->data().isEmpty())
            buf->setData(buf->dataGenerator()->operator()());
        buf->setSyncData(true);
        buf->setAccessType(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::AccessType::ReadWrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very fimiliar with Qt but `data()` appears to return by value which means you are string a pointer to a temporary, which never ends well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the file [$QTDIR/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qarraydata.h](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qarraydata.h), we see this:

```
struct Q_CORE_EXPORT QArrayData
{
   [...]

   static const QArrayData shared_null[2];
   static QArrayData *sharedNull() Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return const_cast<QArrayData*>(shared_null); }
}
```

... so we see that `QArrayData::shared_null` is a static/singleton `QArrayData` object (actually it's an array of two of them).  Presumably it is being used as a sentinel-object; i.e. when another data structure such as [Qt3DRender::QBuffer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer.html) doesn't have a valid `QArrayData` object to point to, it points to `shared_null` instead, as a way to indicate that fact.  Using a singleton rather than `nullptr` is useful in some situations because it means that their code doesn't have to guard every dereference with a `if (buffer() != NULL)` to avoid crashing when no valid `QArrayData` object is available.

As for the `+24` part, that indicates that your pointer is 24 bytes past the memory location where the `QArrayData::shared_null` object starts at.  From looking at the code in `qarraydata.h`, it appears that the `constData()` method calculates the pointer to return by adding a `qptrdiff` offset value to its `this`-pointer; so presumably that offset-value is set to 24 in this case.  However, I think the precise pointer returned is probably not important, since the `QArrayData::shared_null` object is unlikely to contain any usable data in any case, i.e. the array that `data()` is returning is likely of length 0 and therefore the pointer shouldn't be dereferenced.

My suggestion is that before you try to use your `posBufferPtr` pointer, you should call `attribute->buffer()->data().size()` and verify that it's large enough for what you want to do with it, as a sanity-check.  i.e. if you are trying to use the buffer as an array of `float`, the guard your usage of the data with a test like `if (attribute->buffer()->data().size() >= sizeof(float)*num_floats_I_expect_to_be_there)` or similar.